# supplying initialization json string as parameter to jquery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have just begun using jquery datatables in my project and I do like it so far. I have many tables, sometimes 2-3 on a page. Rather than have to keep track of what initialization string I am using for a specific table and trying to remember what webpage its on, I have built an xml file to store all the initialization strings. I built some jquery functions to retrieve the strings on document ready but it never dawned on me how to actually inject the json into the method as a parameter.

If i was doing it manually you would call

```
selector.dataTables(json initializer string here);
```

Once I have that string how do I actually inject it into the method call? Or do I have to create that whole code line and inject it into my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the json data comes in as something like this:

```
{"order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]}
```

You could use jquery to get the JSON via a `HTTP GET` request.

```
$.getJSON('somejson.json',function(data){
   someSelector.dataTables(data)
});
```

Because you are using getJSON it will expect the JSON to be in that format and do the parsing for you.

Or if the JSON is available already(since you are using jquery you can use it to parse the JSON data just in case there may be a browser support issue since IE7 and below does not support `JSON.parse`.):

```
var options = $.parseJSON(someData);
someSelector.dataTables(options)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can assign the json string to a variable...

```
var tableSettings = theJsonString;
selector.dataTables(tableSettings);
```

you may need to convert the string to an object first...

```
//javascript
var tableSettings = JSON.parse(theJsonString);
//jquery
var tableSettings = $.parseJSON(theJsonString);
```